# Change Text to hyperlink

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a main page call "main.html". Inside the main page, there is a table.
Then I created a page call "newPage.html"

The table is in the following format.

```
<table width="707" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="link">Change this to hyperlink</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

How can I use JQuery to change the text "Change this to hyperlink" to a clickable link, linking it to the page "newPage.html"?

So when I click "Change this to hyperlink", I will be redirected to "newPage.html".

All the files is already in the same folder. I am putting the script in a new .js file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $('.link').html(function () {
        return '<a href="newPage.html">' + $(this).text() + '</a>';
    })
});
```

**[jFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kxyth484/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $('.link').text();
$('.link').html('<a href="file.php">' + text + '</a>');
```